# Why does this wget command fail to download this file?

Tags: wget, download

I was wondering why the following command fails to download a pdf file, while pasting the URL in browser's address bar can? (I am trying to learn a little about HTTP, web services, or web applications from this question)

How shall I use wget to download the pdf file?

Thanks.

```
$ wget https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.99.598&rep=rep1&type=pdf
[1] 5696
[2] 5697

Redirecting output to ‘wget-log.1’.
[2]+  Done                    rep=rep1

$ cat wget-log
--2019-11-25 13:30:42--  https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.99.598
Resolving citeseerx.ist.psu.edu (citeseerx.ist.psu.edu)... 130.203.136.95
Connecting to citeseerx.ist.psu.edu (citeseerx.ist.psu.edu)|130.203.136.95|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5641 (5.5K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘download?doi=10.1.1.99.598’

download?doi=10.1.1.99.598                   100%[============================================================================================>]   5.51K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2019-11-25 13:30:42 (453 MB/s) - ‘download?doi=10.1.1.99.598’ saved [5641/5641]

[1]+  Done                    wget https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.99.598
```

Comment: One possible duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280645/accessing-google-translate-via-wget/280649#280649  also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/213004/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/241538/117549

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your shell is interpreting the `&` characters in the URL and they are not getting to `wget`.

You should single quote the string, so your shell treats the whole thing as one string and does not try to interpret special characters:

```
wget 'https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.99.598&rep=rep1&type=pdf'
```